# How to make custom route with custom action in sonata admin using Symfony

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I am new in Symfony as well as sonata admin, I want to make a custom route with custom action in sonata admin.any one know how to make a custom route with custom action and how to call that custom route from twing file ?.

Comment: There is not a sonata-admin for symfony 1.4.

Comment: i am use symphony 3 in that i use sonata admin

Comment: but your tags are symfony1 and symfony 1.4!

Comment: please suggest me is there any way to make a custom route and action in symphony3

Comment: The framework is Symfony not Symphony ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of route in your AdminBundle:

```
<route id="get_driver_location" path="/driver-location">
    <default key="_controller">MyAdminBundle:Core:getlocation</default>
</route>
```

Then you must create a controller called CoreController in the controller directory of your bundle

```
    namespace My\AdminBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\Exception;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CoreController as BaseController;

    class CoreController extends BaseController {

    public function getlocationAction() {
        //your logic here
       ......
       return $this->render($this->getAdminPool()->getTemplate('driver'), array(
                    'base_template' => $this->getBaseTemplate());
    }

    }
```

> Edit: Add Twig:

```
-Resources

  -views

    -Core

      -driver.html.twig
```

in the file driver.html.twig you make a route

```
<div>
                <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ path('get_driver_location') }}" role="button">
                    {{ "example"|trans({}, "MyAdminBundle") }}
                </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: how to cal above route from view twig file ?

Comment: It give me below error.  Error:  "The controller for URI \"\/admin\/department_details\/4614\" is not callable. Expected method \"retrieveDepartmentDetailsAction\......"

Comment: Please, when you have an error, edit you post  that contains all necessary informations about the error.

Comment: 1 ) 
I add Below code in vendor\sonata-project\admin-bundle\Resources\config\routing\sonata_admin.xml file
<route id="get_department_details" path="/department_details/{id}">
        <default key="_controller">
             AppBundle:CRUD:retrieveDepartmentDetailsAction</default>
 </route>
2)Call Route from Twig file  
<form method="post" action="{{ path('get_department_details',{'id': pefix_value_access.MedicalProvider.id}) }}" id="frm_department_details" class="frm_department_details" name="frm_department_details">
3)Make a Function in CRUD Controller in appbundle folder

Comment: I Set above code and It give me Error below:

There is no `_sonata_admin` defined for the controller `AppBundle\\Controller\\CRUDController` and the current route `get_department_details`"

Comment: no, never change the code in the vendor. you should add a new file called sonata_admin.xml  in your bundle which will be contain the new route

Comment: ok let me change it but one question is in which folder i make a sonata_admin.xml file ?

Comment: I make a sonata_admin.xml file in below folder of my bunddle

D:\xampp\htdocs\meopin_2\trunk\src\AppBundle\Resources\config\routing\

But it give me error Below

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "get_department_details" as such route does not exist.").

Comment: please help me something is missing or wrong from my side , please suggest me

Comment: thanks for help it is done few change in your code and it will be done

Comment: and I also Folow 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonata-devs/8GK0kpa2cik link